# Acer Aspire 5532 Overheating

Tags: xubuntu, acer, fan, overheating, aspire

Had the laptop for about a year, when in Windows it never happens, but seems to happen frequently in Xubuntu 11.04. I've looked almost everywhere for increasing the fan speeds, because it never kicks into high gear, just a steady pace for idle use. lm-sensors doesn't show fan speeds, just the temps of the CPU.

As far as http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1740140 thread goes, I've already got the latest kernel.

Fan is clear of dust, and it runs at an average temperature until the GPU is needed

```
$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:       +85.0°C  (crit = +200.0°C)                  

k8temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Core0 Temp:  +76.0°C                                    
Core1 Temp:  -49.0°C
```

Shortly after this it shuts off from overheating. When I can get it to cool off I'll give what I can for an idle temp.

I can't tell if it's a fan speed issue, or a special fan for the GPU that isn't supported.

Comment: do your fans work? You should hear them if they do. If temperature is high they must start working louder.

Comment: They work, just not full speed.  http://www.netbooktech.com/2008/09/17/fix-the-acer-aspire-one-noisy-fan-for-both-windows-and-linux/ seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with an Acer Aspire 5315 which was given to me to mend.
The answer is to download the latest BIOS from Acer and flash it.
The issue arises as several (maybe all) Acer models use the Acer installed software to manage the fan. If that software is removed either because the user doesn't want it, to update Windows, or as I did, to install Ubuntu, then the fan will not work correctly. It may start when the laptop is booted up but if the machine hibernates, sleeps etc then the fan will not restart causing overheating and cut-off.
It seems that Acer acknowledged this some time ago and used a BIOS upgrade to correct the problem. 
I did this with my machine and now have had no problem for 3 weeks (as opposed to cutting-out every few minutes before).